# <ul> <li> Hide/show inner text only not <i> icon tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, show-hide, buttonclick

In jQuery I need to hide/show inner text of anchor tag.
Here is html :

```
<div id="side_bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-cog"></i>General Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-cog"></i>Other Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-user"></i>User</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

on a button click I need to hide/show only inner text `General Settings`,`Settings`,`User`.

I tried this :

```
$.each($('#side_bar').find('ul').find('li'), function (key, value) {
  $(this).find('a').contents().get(0).nodeValue.hide();
});
```

but it's not working.

got this error in console ::

```
TypeError: $(...).find(...).contents(...).get(...).nodeValue is null
    $(this).find('a').contents().get(0).nodeValue.hide();
```

I need result to only hide show `<a>` tag's inner text, not the icon. I try to make collapse sidebar menu.

`NOTE` :: I must not need to add `<span>` in to menu.

Comment: "not working" is not an error message or description, please explain in more detail - tell us any errors that you get, or explain the current result you get vs your expected result.

Comment: Maybe its a type but your `<li>` are missing the `</li>`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen `</li>` is optional.

Comment: What's not working? There are problems with your jQuery selectors as you've got multiple `find()`s in there which aren't needed, but it's difficult to suggest a fix if we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Try to put text inside `<i>` tag in a `<span>` and hide that tag

Comment: `<li>` I just miss in this question only, sorry for that, but in real html that is perfect

Comment: also you said "on button click". Where's the button, and the click event handler?

Comment: Im not sure you can actually hide the node value like this. That is to say, you cant just hide the text. Typically, the text would be in a span with some class and this would be trivial.

Comment: @ADyson I update my question.

Comment: @Ramon-san I update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution strictly based on your existing description.

First there is a button, with a click event handler, since you say you want this to happen on a button click. Second, you only want to hide the "inner text". I take this to mean you don't want to hide the `<i>` tag. The easiest way is to put the text into a span with a class, then it's straightforward to locate - all the `find` stuff is completely unnecessary, you can use a simple selector:

```
<div id="side_bar">
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-cog"></i><span class="menuText">General Settings</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-cog"></i><span class="menuText">Other Settings</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-user"></i><span class="menuText">User</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="myButton" type="button">Click to hide</button>

$(function() {
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#side_bar li a .menuText").hide();
  });
});
```

OR, as per your last update, you're certain you can't/won't add a `<span>` into the markup, you can just hide the text. I've also included a feature to save and restore the text later when the button is clicked, by keeping the text in a `data-` attribute of the anchor:

```
<div id="side_bar">
  <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-cog"></i>General Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-cog"></i>Other Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-user"></i>User</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="myButton" type="button">Click to hide</button>

$(function() {
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#side_bar li a").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        if (el.text() != '') {
            el.data('originalText', el.text());
            el.text('');
        }
        else {
            el.text(el.data('originalText'));
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xcxv682h/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap you text by `span`'s and use simple selector like :

```
$('#side_bar li a span')
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#toggle-display').on('click', function(){
  $('#side_bar li a span').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id='toggle-display'>Toggle display</button>
<div id="side_bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-cog"></i><span>General Settings</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-cog"></i><span>Other Settings</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-fw fa-user"></i><span>User</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```